# Need support with logic behind "approve post if 10 people like it" feature

Tags: php, mysql

Right now I have a voting system on my website that stores all votes in a **votes** table. in **votes** table I have a field named **item_name** which contains **id** of article that was liked. All article information including it's id is located in a **stories** table. In **votes** table each there is a field named **vote_value** which can be 1 and -1 and depending on what user put for vote (like / dislike).

I need to somehow sum up all records for certain article and if they sum up as 10 or more make article approved. To approve article I have a field in **stories** table which is named as **showing** it can have two values 0 - unproved 1 - approved. So somehow I need to make it so once an article gets 10 likes (as a sum of all records from **votes** table) set **showing** to 1 (showing is in a **stories** table).

Preferably without any queries, say make database check for sums of vote_value of article that has a showing = 0 (and ignore ones that have showing = 1, so less server resources are used) . I'm not sure if this is a lot to do for a server, maybe it's not the most efficient way.

**EDIT:** Users can un-vote and change vote value if they like (e.g. they liked the post, but they can change it to unlike).

My Database Structure:

**stories**

---

### [image]

**votes**

---

[image]

Comment: So you just want a query to run after every vote to check the count of like votes? Or do you want a database trigger to automatically update 'showing'?

Comment: database to automatically update showing is more efficient I guess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE stories SET showing = 1 WHERE id IN (SELECT id,  SUM (vote_value) as total_votes from votes  GROUP BY item_name WHERE total_votes  > 10)
```

What I think will be efficient (depending on the amount of voting):

When a vote is cast:

```
Insert into votes set vote_value = '-1' where id = xx;
UPDATE stories SET showing = 1 WHERE id IN (SELECT id,  SUM (vote_value) as total_votes from votes WHERE id=xx AND total_votes  > 10);
```

That last one could be broken up with PHP, because this is a bit of a strange way of doing it.

Comment: is there a way to do this without query, say make database check sums once in 15 min and if some have 10 set showing to 1?

Comment: yes, you could use a cron job for that. Just make a PHP script that runs this query, and set a cron job to run this script every 15 minutes. On windows machines you can use scheduled tasks. Depending on your provider setting this up can be easy.

Comment: is it efficient? I mean will it be to much for a server to do so if there are 5000+ different records?

Comment: It will manage, but for it to be really efficient, you need to change your approach. Because now it will check every record every time, even when nothing may have changed. It might be more efficient to just check the number of votes for one item when a vote is cast, that way the database will only be updated when something has changed, also, you will only be summing up one item.

Answer (score 1):

your SQL query should look like this

SELECT SUM(vote_value) AS totalvotes FROM votes WHERE item_name='myexpectedvalue'

Comment: is there a way to do this without query, say make database check sums once in 15 min and if some have 10 set showing to 1?

Answer (score 1):

The SQL looks something like this:

```
UPDATE stories SET showing=1 WHERE id IN
(SELECT item_name FROM votes GROUP BY item_name HAVING SUM(vote_value) >= 10)
```

This will update any story that has a sum vote_value of 10 or over.

Comment: is there a way to do this without query, say make database check sums once in 15 min and if some have 10 set showing to 1?

Comment: you'd have to make a cron job for that. btw, the query in saratis's answer is better then mine, because you need only one query, in my example, you'd need 1 query to get it, and one for updating. I was just looking up how to do that :p